# how to install KDE on Ubuntu ? I tried to install kubuntu, but installations failed 2 times

Tags: installation, kde

how to install KDE on Ubuntu ? I tried to install kubuntu, but installations failed 2 times. is there any way to use KDE under default distribution of ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming from you question that you tried to install Kubunutu as an operating system, that failed so you installed vanilla Ubuntu and now want to install KDE?

That should be as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

you can replace `kubuntu-desktop` with `kde-full` for extras or `kde-plasma-desktop` for the bare minimum. For more detail see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingKDE).

Answer (score 0):

try this in your terminal

```
 sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop
```

then logout and at login select kde plasma desktop from kdm